# jQuery ajax + htaccess

Tags: jquery

I have wildcard dns on the server and dynamic subdomains working properly on the server. However there is a problem with the Ajax file processing through jQuery.

Below is the jQuery Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'process.php',
    data: 'grpid=' + group_select.val(),
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#grpsrv').html(data);            
      $('#spinner').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

So internally file will be processed as for example *process.php?grpid=88*.

In the .htaccess file the line is written as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^process.php?([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /home/server-path/user-website/process.php?grpid=$1
```

But when I echo the `$_GET['grpid']` on *process.php* it is showing blank value.

How to write a `RewriteRule` for Ajax file?

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like your first regex is not working correctly. It will probably match your group id, but not `grpid=someid`. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^process.php?grpid=([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /home/server-path/user-website/process.php?grpid=$1
```

Also, you might want to enable [rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog) to see if your rule is getting triggered correctly in the first place, and watch the error logs, too.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to just let mod_rewrite handle it using the RewriteRule `[QSA]` flag

```
RewriteRule ^process.php$ /home/server-path/user-website/process.php [QSA]
```

`[QSA]` tells Apache to copy the original request's query string to the new url's query string.